# Ajuda com IF e ELSE em session_start()

Tags: php

Peço a ajuda dos amigos, pois estou com dificuldade para criar um IF/ELSE para determinar qual conteúdo da variável `$logo` entrará primeiro.

É o seguinte eu preciso que ao acessar a pagina principal "http://www.efacilfacil.com/", seja carregado o logo da É Fácil Fácil (**Conforme esta no endereço mencionado para acesso**) acreditando que a SESSION ainda não foi carregada. Mas depois de alterarem a imagem via Painel Adm.(**Acesso pelo endereço mencionado**), a nova imagem seja carregada.

Para isso tentei criar o código PHP (**relacionado abaixo**) para determinar quando a `session_start()` deve carregar a variável referente a imagem que foi trocada, mas como menciono no inicio do POST, sem sucesso, pois mesmo depois da troca de imagem, ele continua carregando o logo da É Fácil Fácil.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { // Se a Session não for iniciada
    $logo = 'img/logo_tipo.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
}else{ // Se não
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.
if(isset($_SESSION)) { // Se a Session for iniciada
    $logo = ''.$_SESSION['logo'].''; // Carrega esse conteúdo
}}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
</head>

<body style="margin:0;">

    <div align="center" style=" margin-top:5px; width:100%;">

 <img  width="150" height="auto" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" /><br />

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Bem agradeço a atenção dos amigos, e no aguardo de boas dicas para solucionar o meu problema, caso tenha solução.

Abraços à todos.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim, eu faria assim:

Quando a Imagem é definida:

```
session_start(); // isto existe sempre
$_SESSION['Logo'] = 'COLOCADA/ADMIN/IMAGEM.jpp'; // Definir uma imagem 'default', caso ainda não se tenha colocado uma nova entretanto

if(isset($_SESSION['iniciada'])) {
     $_SESSION['Logo'] = 'NOVA/IMAGEM.JPG';
}

....
<img  width="150" height="auto" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['Logo']; ?>" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a session.
if($_SESSION['logo']==FALSE) { // Se a Session não for iniciada
    $logo = 'img/logo_tipo.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
}else{ // Se não
    $logo = $_SESSION['logo']; // Carrega esse conteúdo
}
?>
```

Eu faria desta forma

Answer (score 0):

Tenta iniciar a seção no inicio do código, e no if verifica...

```
          if(!isset($_SESSION['logo'])){}
```

Se não ser certo comenta ai, talvez eu não tenha entendido direito a pergunta...

Comment: Agradeço aos amigos Miguel, André Baill e ao LocalHost, pelas dicas e a solução foi dada com a dica do LocalHost, pois foi somente acrescentar na linha da SESSION não iniciada a variável `['logo']` para que funcionasse perfeito, mas testei também o código do André Baill, que funcionou do perfeito exatamente do jeito que ele postou. Valeu Mesmo, entrem no endereço (http://www.efacilfacil.com/) para verem o resultado, pois vou deixar por algum tempo no ar. Mais uma vez, meu muito obrigado aos amigos, valeu mesmo pela força. Abraços à todos.